# RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, pyyaml, pyrogram

This is a [forked repository](https://github.com/botsbyvivek/mail) from Github and when I try to deploy it to Heroku it shows the error:

```
2023-12-31T03:10:27.965787+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-12-31T03:10:27.965828+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown
2023-12-31T03:10:27.965992+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._executor.open()
2023-12-31T03:10:27.966013+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 87, in open
2023-12-31T03:10:27.966072+00:00 app[web.1]:     thread.start()
2023-12-31T03:10:27.966088+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 992, in start
2023-12-31T03:10:27.966229+00:00 app[web.1]:     _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
2023-12-31T03:10:27.966249+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown
2023-12-31T03:10:28.174616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-12-31T03:10:28.197914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It says:

> RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown"

Help me to solve this.

I'm trying to create a Telegram bot using that Github repo

Comment: Is that the _entire_ error messages? Have you checked the logs _before_ that? It seems the app is _already_ crashed at that point and is _already_ shutting down, but your app is still trying to create a new thread. Check the logs from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.12 introduced a change that prevents creating new threads after the main thread has exited. It's not clear yet whether it is considered a bug and will be reverted. See [CPython issue #115533](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/115533) for details.

- You could simply downgrade to Python 3.11 for now.
- Change the logic of the main thread such that it doesn't exit prematurely, but *waits* for all child threads before returning. This is usually done by calling [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method on any child threads, or converting the thread spawning to use `with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: ...` [(see documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example), which automatically waits at the end of the block.